# Swift. Facebook picture url returning nil

Tags: swift, facebook, url, null, profile-picture

I'm trying to create a `SKSpriteNode` with the texture of a profile picture from the facebook users friend. I have the right ID but its still returning nil.

My code:

```
let pictureData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "http://graph.facebook.com/\(friendObject["id"]!)/picture?type=large"))
picture.texture = SKTexture(image: UIImage(data: pictureData!)!)
```

This is the error I'm recieving:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running that URL in a browser to confirm the ID is not nil and the URL works?

I think I also remember having this issue when I was using FBSDK.  The function trying to use that image is being called before the URL has been downloaded.  You need to put the code in a URL session like this.

```
func getFBProfileImage(profileId: String, completion: ((image: UIImage?) -> Void)) {
let url:String = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(profileId)/picture?type=large"

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!) {(data, response, error) in
    completion(image: UIImage(data: data))
}

   task.resume()
 }

 getFBProfileImage(friendObject(id)) { image     in
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        picture.texture = SKTexture(image:UIImage(data: image))
      }
 }
```

Comment: It returns this error: Use of unresolved identifier 'completion'. Yes I have tried running the URL in a browser, and it definitely works.

Comment: Sorry, was trying from memory.  I've edited now to include everything. You call it with getFBProfileImage()

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answar by seing this post:

[Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

All i had to do was allowing my app to connect to the website.